# There's any way to format the Locale obj that comes from Date-fns into ISO 639-1 Code?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, date, frontend, date-fns

I'm using a Date-fns function to calculate the time that has passed since a certain action was executed, the app that I'm working in has two languages available: English and Spanish.
here's the code:

```
import { formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns'
import { es, enUS } from 'date-fns/locale'

  const timeAgo = computed((): string =>
      formatDistanceToNow(new Date(props.data.date as Date), {
        addSuffix: true,
        locale: store.getters.getLanguage === 'EN' ? enUS : es
      })
    )
```

A better solution and what I'm being asked to do is a direct match between our language state store keys which are EN and ES with the locale Date-fns obj which are enUS (here's the problem) => Need to turn it to ISO 639-1 Code before using it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "en" and "en-US" are different because the represent two different ideas. The first is English as a language, the second is English as spoken in the United States. But for the purposes of this question, I don't know why you need to convert it to ISO 639-1; what you really need is a mapping between one way of saying something and another. Typically this is done with an object `const mapLang = { EN: enUS, ES: es };` then `locale: mapLang[store.getters.getLanguage]`.

Comment: But the [documentation for the Locale object](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/Locale) says the `code` property returns the ISO 639-1 Code...